# adehabitatHR: In proj4string(xy) : CRS object has comment, which is lost in output

Tags: kernel-density, proj, adehabitathr

I'm trying to create `kernel density` map from point data (available as `.shp` and `.csv`) for 5 different species,at global scale. For some individual, there is only one point locality, but for the others there are few to several points. I will use the output map of KDE to identify the hotspots. I'm using `adehabitatHR` to produce KDE map as below:

```
library("sp")
library("rgdal")
library("rgeos")
 
# load the data layer
data.Points <- readOGR("D:/FGH/merged","data")

#Defining a CRS with sp cause coordinate reference systems are represented differently when PROJ < 6 and PROJ >= 6.
crs_wgs84 <- CRS(SRS_string = "EPSG:4326") # WGS 84 has EPSG code 4326
class(crs_wgs84)
wkt_wgs84 <- wkt(crs_wgs84)
cat(wkt_wgs84)

#Set the CRS of a Spatial* object in sp
data.Points2 <- data.Points
coordinates(data.Points2) <-  ~ x + y
slot(data.Points2, "proj4string") <- crs_wgs84
    
library(raster)
library(adehabitatHR)
    
# Define the Domain               
x <- seq(-179.8300, 179.2461, by=0.083333333) # resolution is the pixel size you desire
y <- seq(-42, 52, by=0.083333333)
xy <- expand.grid(x=x,y=y)
coordinates(xy) <- ~x+y
gridded(xy) <- TRUE
class(xy)

# runs the kernel density estimation
kde.output <- kernelUD(data.Points2, h="href", grid = xy)
```

However, I got this error when either using `.shp` or `.csv` input file:

```
In proj4string(xy) :   CRS object has comment, which is lost in output
```

I went through `https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/vignettes/CRS_warnings.html` and `https://inbo.github.io/tutorials/tutorials/spatial_crs_coding/`, and did some modifies as above but the warning message is remained!

So, how can I get rid of this warning message? Is there any wrong command used?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can ignore that message. The solution is to leave sp/rgdal/rgeos/raster behind and use their replacements `sf` and/or `terra`.

Comment: Thank you @Robert Hijmans for your advise. I switched to spatstat and I will compare the bandwidth selection results of the both packages.